# Remove countries/states CDATA from WooCommerce Checkout (html code)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a list of all states and cities in html code. Actually I do not need states and cities.

[image]

I can remove them by adding this code to the functions.php

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', function( $states ){
       unset( $states['AF'] );
       unset( $states['AL'] );
       unset( $states['AO'] );
       unset( $states['AR'] );

       // AND SO ON

       return $states;
   }, 999);
```

But if I want to remove them all with code, I get an error:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', function( $states ){
       unset( $states );
        return $states;
   }, 999);
```

> Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php on line 580

Is listing all the countries the only way to remove them from the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by creating an empty array

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', function( $states ){
        $states = array();
        return $states;
   }, 999);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but this could easily be resolved with one line, since `__return_empty_array` already does what you want.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', '__return_empty_array', 99 );
```

Comment: Amazing!, I never knew that `__return_empty_array` exists.